# How to perform multiple actions with a single fragment call back

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

So, I recently got involved with fragments and learnt how to use a buttonClick to call back and communicate with the activity. Until recently, i've been performing a single function with my callback. But now, i want to perform more than one kind of activity with it. Basically, the callbacks' itemListener is used to switch fragments, animated from left to right. Now another button was introduced, to switch the fragments in the opposite direction, so any advice on how to do this, would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
public class ExamFragment extends Fragment{
    private static OnItemClickedListener sDummyCallbacks = new OnItemClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemClicked(Parameters params) {

        }
    };
    OnItemClickedListener mListener = sDummyCallbacks;

    private Button nextButton, prevButton;

    // firstly, create the interface
        public interface OnItemClickedListener {
            public void OnItemClicked(Parameters params);
        }

        //To ensure that the host activity implements the interface
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            try {
                mListener = (OnItemClickedListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnItemClickedListener");
            }
        }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam_fragment, container,
            false);

    nextButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    prevButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.prevButton);

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mListener.OnItemClicked(null);
            ++num;
        }

    });

    prevButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mListener.OnItemClicked(null);
            --num;
        }

    });




    return view;
    }
```

and here's my activity

```
public class ExamActivity extends Activity implements ExamFragment.OnItemClickedListener{

    Fragment my = new ExamFragment();
    private int time;
    private boolean timerHasStarted = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exam);
        lockRotation();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, my);
        transaction.commit();




 }

    @Override
    public void OnItemClicked(Parameters recieveparams) {
        my = new ExamFragment();


                            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_anim, R.animator.exit_anim);
                            transaction.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, my);
                            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                            transaction.commit();

                }


    }
```

the next button does the animation as shown in the code, but the previous button is meant to do it in the opposite direction, introducing a static variable may help me determine which button was clicked, but i don't like statics, and i feel there's a better way to do it. Sorry if my question is still too vague.

Comment: What about Parameters object ? You can keep a variable in Parameters class like int actionType or something like this right?

Comment: yeah, i did that, used an int parameter to recognize which button was pressed, thanks anyways